# How do I solve an Angular form field error?

Tags: angular, forms

I'm getting an error in Developer Tools Console concerning input fields on a form.

The error reads "ngModel is used within a form tag, either the name attribute must be set or...".

And a proposed solution is given: Example 1:

But the problem is that I am doing exactly what Developer Tools suggests.  Here is my code:

```
<input class="form-control" name="name" [(ngModel)]="product.name" />
```

I can comment out this particular form field only to get the exact same error feedback on the following field.

Any ideas? This makes no sense! (to me)

Answer (score 0):

if you are using ngForm then name attribute is required or you can add following to

```
<input class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="product.name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"/>
```

if you think that you have already provided name attribute then perhaps you want to make sure that browser has updated code also (ng build, ng serve)

Comment: No, I tried this earlier and I still got the same error

Comment: if you are getting same error on each field then it indicates the problem is somewhere else, can you post markup of full ngform?

Comment: It's a big form but here's the first part of it...

<form novalidate #form="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="save(form)">
     <div class="form-group">
          <label>Name</label>
          <input class="form-control" name="name" [(ngModel)]="product.name" />
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
          <label>Category</label>  
          <span>&nbsp</span>    

          <select [(ngModel)]="product.category"> 
               <option value="action">Action</option>

Comment: it's hard to guess the problem without full html, perhaps you can drop it in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), I can see <select> tag doesn't have name attribute but there might be some other problem too, full markup will help

Comment: Brilliant!  Thank you Kedar.  Actually by fixing up the <select> field, somehow it fixed the seemingly unrelated problem being reported by Developer Tools.  So, back in business.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to add ReactiveFormsModule / FormsModule to your

app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [PageContactComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
  ]
})
```

Comment: I'm not using the ReactiveFormsModule in this case.

Comment: and FormsModule?